# How to install mcz file to squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm squeak beginner. And I want a help about library install on squeak.

in squeaksource.com, there are libraries that I want to install 
but when I execute

```
(Installer ss project: 'WebClient')
    install: 'WebClient-Core';
```

I failed to install for network problem.

So I download mcz file to pc, but I don't know how to install that mcz file to squeak.
Would you let me know how to handle mcz file??

ps. thanks for reading my poor english. If you feedback wrong english expression, it also very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

Squeaksource (the code repository you were trying to access) was probably was down. It happens. Your script was fine, though (apart from the trailing ';').

Try

```
(Installer ss project: 'WebClient') install: 'WebClient-Core'
```

or

```
MczInstaller installFileNamed: '/path/to/WebClient-Core-ar.89.mcz'
```

Comment: b.t.w. I would've assumed you could load your downloaded mcz file via the "file list" tool or programmatically via "MczInstaller installFileNamed: '/Volumes/Fast/Squeak/Fresh Images/Squeak4.2 Final/package-cache/WebClient-Core-ar.89.mcz'", but neither seems to do the right thing (may be a bug).

Comment: MczInstaller installFileNamed message was work!!!! I successed to install libraries for your help. thanks a lot. My netwrok problem seems related to firewall condition of my office.

Answer (score 3):

you can also just drag and drop the mzc file into the image, and when the popup appears you choose "file in".

cheers